# How to substring a string in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string in SQL like

> CMS/00014456582/**693362**/004535/JCR_110914_NEW_4535 CMS

I want to read a string in bold. 
How to read that string using substring function.

```
select SUBSTRING('CMS/00014456582/693362/004535/JCR_110914_NEW_4535 CMS',18,6) AS column_name
```

This is one answer for my question. But I want to read string after two '/' - file seperator.

I have another string which is like  **INF/000079160100/P - (34) cases NET BANKING** and I want read the (this) value .eg**34**
thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is Sql Server, please remove the MySql tag

Comment: Are the lengths dynamic or fixed? Are you looking to do this on a single value or a set of values?

Comment: Be clear what is final expected output

Comment: @AdriaanStander this is dynamic lenghts.

Comment: @NoDisplayName I want to read only that string which are between secon '/' and third '/'

Comment: Please help me for the same .Please read the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do if the the string that has to be selected is of fixed length and after 2nd occurance of '/'

```
DECLARE @document varchar(64);
SELECT @document = 'CMS/00014456582/693362/004535/JCR_110914_NEW_4535 CMS'
select Substring(@document, CHARINDEX('/', @document,(SELECT CHARINDEX('/', @document)+1))+1,6)
```

Comment: thanks solve my problem..

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Text NVARCHAR(1000)

select @Text = SUBSTRING('CMS/00014456582/693362/004535/JCR_110914_NEW_4535 CMS', CHARINDEX('/', 'CMS/00014456582/693362/004535/JCR_110914_NEW_4535 CMS') + 1,1000) 

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('/', @Text) + 1,6) AS column_name
```

Answer (score 2):

A pretty flexible way to get what you want is by the use of a `recursive CTE`. The CTE expression will essentially give you the position and the corresponding index of all '/' contained in the string:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = 'CMS/00014456582/693362/004535/JCR_110914_NEW_4535 CMS'

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CHARINDEX('/', @string) AS pos, idx = 1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CHARINDEX('/', @string, pos+1) AS pos, idx + 1 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE pos > 0
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

produces:

```
pos idx
-------
4   1
16  2
23  3
30  4
0   5
```

Using the above CTE you can easily extract ***any part*** of the string contained within, say, 1st and 2nd slashes, or 2nd and 3rd, etc:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CHARINDEX('/', @string) AS pos, idx = 1 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CHARINDEX('/', @string, pos+1) AS pos, idx + 1 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE pos > 0
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, 
                 (SELECT pos FROM CTE WHERE idx = 2) + 1, 
                 (SELECT pos FROM CTE WHERE idx = 3) - (SELECT pos FROM CTE WHERE idx = 2) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had wrote a function to split my string data. This can be beneficial for you too :

```
   CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SPLIT]
(
    @ROWDATA NVARCHAR(2000),
    @SPLITON NVARCHAR(5)
)  
RETURNS @RTNVALUE TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    DATA NVARCHAR(100)
) 

AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @CNT INT
    SET @CNT =  LEN(@SPLITON)

WHILE (CHARINDEX(@SPLITON,@ROWDATA)>0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @RTNVALUE (DATA)
    SELECT 
        DATA = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ROWDATA,1,CHARINDEX(@SPLITON,@ROWDATA)-1)))

    SET @ROWDATA = SUBSTRING(@ROWDATA,CHARINDEX(@SPLITON,@ROWDATA)+1,LEN(@ROWDATA))
    SET @CNT = @CNT + @CNT
END

INSERT INTO @RTNVALUE (DATA)
SELECT DATA = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ROWDATA))

RETURN
END
```

Create this function And then

```
SELECT DATA FROM SPLIT ('CMS/00014456582/693362/004535/JCR_110914_NEW_4535 CMS','/');
```

This will return a table that each row is "/" seperated data of your string.

Comment: nic code..but solve my problem by using second one..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking
Please try the below it helps you if the bold area length isn't always 6 digits

```
    DECLARE @document varchar(64);
    DECLARE @start int;
    DECLARE @lenght int;
    SELECT @document = 'CMS/00014456582/693362/004535/JCR_110914_NEW_4535 CMS'
    select @start = CHARINDEX('/',@document,CHARINDEX('/',@document)+1)+1
    select @lenght = CHARINDEX('/',@document,CHARINDEX('/',@document,CHARINDEX('/',@document)+1)+1) - @start
    select Substring(@document,@start, @lenght)
```